# Strategy for finding the possible "callee tree" for a given C# method

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a method A that can call either method B or C depending on some condition (it would call method B for one condition, method C for some other condition).
Now, suppose B could call either method D or E (again, based on different conditions), and C could call F or G (based on different conditions).

Imagine that I have a "callee tree" such as this but the tree is large.
I want to find out what that tree is (ie, the list of methods) without having to MANUALLY follow each possible path.  Doing this MANUALLY will be time-consuming and error-prone.

What I'm looking for is a strategy or a tool that will give this info to me quickly.
I've seen some third-party tools, but they seem a bit heavy and I'm not sure if they will do this exactly.

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Unless call hierarchy provides this functionality, you'll need to search/write a roslyn analyzer for this.

Comment: You are running into what we call the "fan out" problem in static analysis; remember that it will be complicated *enormously* by virtual methods which by definition are dispatched based on the run-time type information of the receiver. If you can say a little more about what aim you intend to accomplish here, I might be able to give you some more targeted advice.

Comment: In particular, suppose you have a call to `ToString` on a variable of type `object` in some method; do you care about the fact that there are literally *millions* of methods that it could be calling?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Eric.  Things like ToString() I wouldn't care about.  I'm interested in calls to methods that have more "functionality".   It turns that just yesterday I found that ReSharper does this via its "Inspect > Outgoing Calls" feature, so I think I'm good.
However, for fun, I would like to tackle writing such a tool.  I'm sure I'd learn a lot about C# and .NET by taking this on.
I'm just a mid-level C# developer without a CS background so I'm not sure how to go about doing this.
Any advice?
Maybe defining a workable plan for world peace would be an easier project?  ;)

Comment: Can you say more about what you intend to do with such a tool? There may already be a tool that does what you want. Also, are you trying to solve this problem *only for source code* or do you need to solve it for libraries that you do not have the source code to?

Comment: For now, I just want the tool to be used on source code.  Maybe later I'll want to extend it to libraries.   I actually found that ReSharper does have such a tool in its "Inspect > Outgoing Calls" feature.
However, as a programming exercise I'd like to write something myself.  I guess one issue would be how to integrate it into Visual Studio (or some other IDE?) if such integration is possible.

Comment: @user3390380: If you are new to the code analysis space then I strongly encourage you to study the Roslyn API. We designed it to enable all kinds of code analysis: lexical, grammatical and, in your case, semantic. The basic idea is that you construct an immutable project with all the source code and references, and you can then issue queries against source code locations, like "tell me the type of the expression on line 10, offset 20" or "tell me what method call is at..." and so on. Roslyn was designed to integrate into the IDE; it is how the C# team writes IDE integrations.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a one time thing, and you don't mind modifying all your methods a bit, something like this may help. You can write a utility function to get the name of the current method like so:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static string GetCurrentMethod()
{
    var st = new StackTrace();
    var sf = st.GetFrame(1);
    return sf.GetMethod().Name;
}
```

And call the `GetCurrentMethod()` from all the methods you want to trace. Based on your described method hierarchy, it would look like this:

```
static void A(int num)
{
    Console.Write(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
    if (num > 0)
        B(num);
    else
        C(num);
}

static void B(int num)
{
    Console.Write(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
    if (num < 5)
        D(num);
    else
        E(num);
}

static void C(int num)
{
    Console.Write(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
    if (num < -10)
        F(num);
    else
        G(num);
}

static void D(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
}

static void E(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
}

static void F(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
}

static void G(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentMethod() + " -> ");
}
```

This is a simple example where I print to the console, but you can modify this to write to a file. I've used `WriteLine()` in the 'leaf' methods here in order to jump to a new line, but those are things you can figure out based on your method hierarchy.

Now with few example numbers that fit my conditions, I can get all possible trees:

### Calling:

```
A(-11);
A(-5);
A(0);
A(4);
A(7);
```

### Output:

> A -> C -> F ->
>
> A -> C -> G ->
>
> A -> C -> G ->
>
> A -> B -> D ->
>
> A -> B -> E ->

---

### EDIT

You can probably do something like this in order to avoid having to worry about giving all correct initial conditions, and then finally remove duplicates from the final output:

```
for (int i = -15; i < 15; i++)
{
    A(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you, @Sach.   My apologies, but I was probably unclear in my orginal post.  The situation is that the tree I'm trying to capture is very broad and deep, so I don't know the methods in the tree.  I want a strategy that, given that I only know method A, I want to find all the methods A calls, all the methods that called by the methods A calls, and so on.

Comment: Ah that definitely changes the game. I think then you'd probably have to go for a Roslyn analyzer as the other commenter suggested. This solution was in the case where you had access to methods and can be done with a simple mod.